# PHP Uncaught CurlException

Tags: php, curl

I am developing an open id app for facebook.

I am getting this error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed thrown in C:\wamp\www\x\modules\openid\facebook.php on line 614`

Around there is this code:

```
 if (isset($opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER])) {
  $existing_headers = $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER];
  $existing_headers[] = 'Expect:';
  $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $existing_headers;
} else {
  $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array('Expect:');
}

curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
  $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
    'error_code' => curl_errno($ch),
    'error'      => array(
      'message' => curl_error($ch),
      'type'    => 'CurlException',
    ),
  ));
  curl_close($ch);
  throw $e;
}
curl_close($ch);
return $result;
}
```

The actual line 614 is:

> ```
>   $e = new FacebookApiException(array(
> ```

I' m running windows 7 and WAMP with php 5.2.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason it wants you to verify the SSL Cert. You can make curl continue working with: (From [`curl`](http://php.net/curl_setopt) )

> **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST**    **FALSE**
>
> to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate. Alternate certificates to verify against can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAINFO option or a certificate directory can be specified with the CURLOPT_CAPATH option. CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST may also need to be TRUE or FALSE if CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER is disabled (it defaults to 2).    TRUE by default as of cURL 7.10. Default bundle installed as of cURL 7.10.

You may also need to check into that as well as the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` setting.

You should also look over this link:  http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=258460

Comment: Disabling verification will certainly make the script work, but is a terrible idea from a security perspective. Peer verification is part of SSL for a reason.

Comment: @AdamKalsey The real solution is to add the CA certs to your host. You are more than welcome to give an answer that ensures "security" to counteract mine instead of simply downvoting and leaving a vague comment, which doesn't help anyone.

Comment: @BradFJacobs How do I add the CA certs to my host?

Comment: The question is about working in local development host. no real need for cert. +1 for answer @BradFJacobs